# CakePHP: agnostic model manipulation

Tags: php, cakephp, activerecord, abstraction, cakephp-2.7

Is there a way to fetch/manipulate a model agnostically in the AppController in order to avoid DRYness in the controllers of the application ? For example:

```
//AppController.php
public function find_all()
{
   return $this->AppModel->find('all'); 
   //I know this does not work but to give you the idea
}
```

And in children controllers of the app:

```
//FoosController.php
public function some_function()
{
   $data = parent::find_all();
   //List of Foo entities
}
```

Or:

```
//BarsController.php
public function some_other_function()
{
   $data = parent::find_all();
   //List of Bar entities
}
```

Is there a solution CakePHP can provide ? Or using reflection, maybe ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Are you sure that you want to _avoid_ DRYness, I'd think that you'd want to _achieve_ it? What exactly is it that you don't want to repeat? Is it really just calls to `Model::find()`, or is there actually more complexity involved? If the latter is the case, then please elaborate on that, because wrapping a simple `Model::find()` call doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is indeed more than the just the Model:find() method... Basically, all the CRUD operations I'm performing on models are exactly the same, that's why I would like to refactor them in the AppController directly. So what I'm really trying to achieve is to manipulate a Model in an abstract way. Using Controller:loadModel($this->modelClass) loads the proper model, but then, how can I use this model to call Model:save() or Model:find() methods ?

Comment: Mmmm, I'm still not sure that I understand your actual problem... are you maybe asking how to use the value of `$this->modelClass` to access an object property?

Comment: I finally figured out a way to achieve what I wanted to do: `$this->{$this->modelClass}->find('all'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to achieve what I was looking for:

```
//AppController.php
public function find_all()
{
   return $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('all'); 
}
```

**NOTE**: If you are performing repetitive CRUD operations without any real business logic or authorization involved (as I currently am), you can also use you these lines of code to persist entites without being aware of the model that is being handled in the `AppController`.

```
//AppController.php
if (!$this->{$this->modelClass}->save($this->request->data))
{
   $validationErrors = $this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors;
   //error logic here
}
else
{
   //success logic here
}
```